# difference between !dir$ and !$omp

Tags: fortran, openmp, xeon-phi

while trying to offload part of my code to MIC card, I encountered 
some directives like `!dir$`
 offload_transfer. Actually, in my code
I was using `!$omp target map directives`. It seems that `!dir$` directives
can do similar job as OpenMP directives, for instance `!dir$ simd`
and `!$omp simd`. My questions:

1) what is the generic name of this directives (if there is one at all)?
Knowing this I could find some information on internet.

2) Do you know some site where I could find all available `!dir$` directives?

3) Can this directives do the same job for offloading to MICs than 
OpenMP (>4.0) ones?

4) Can I combine `!dir$` directives with OpenMP directives?

Thanks.

Comment: These are Intel specific proprietary directives. Consult your compiler's (online or offline) manual. And Intel's articles about programming for XPhi

Comment: Possibly more information can be found [in this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017581/intels-pragma-simd-vs-openmps-pragma-omp-simd)

Comment: Writing new code now it is likely better to stick with the portable OpenMP constructs rather than switch to the Intel specific directives unless you have a very strong reason to do otherwise.